# 91 Bottles of ASCII-beer on the Wall

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Given a single integer `x` where `0 <= x <= 91` output a stack of bottles of beer with that many bottles (and shelves) missing. For simplicity sake I'll only show the first 6 bottles and what it would be for each of the first inputs.

Here's the stack of bottles, each number is the bottle you should remove for that input (1-indexed):

https://pastebin.com/wSpZRMV6

---

*Note, we're using 91 instead of 99 because 99 would result in an unstable stack of bottles.*

---

## Example

With 0 bottles missing (`x=0`):

```
             |=|            
             | |            
             | |            
            /   \           
           .     .          
           |-----|          
           |     |          
           |-----|          
           |_____|          
        =============       
         |=|     |=|        
         | |     | |        
         | |     | |        
        /   \   /   \       
       .     . .     .      
       |-----| |-----|      
       |     | |     |      
       |-----| |-----|      
       |_____| |_____|      
    =====================    
     |=|     |=|     |=|     
     | |     | |     | |     
     | |     | |     | |     
    /   \   /   \   /   \    
   .     . .     . .     .   
   |-----| |-----| |-----|   
   |     | |     | |     |   
   |-----| |-----| |-----|   
   |_____| |_____| |_____|   
=============================
 [THERE ARE MORE UNDER THIS]
```

*For the full output of 0, see here: https://pastebin.com/ZuXkuH6s*

---

With `1` bottle missing (`x=1`):

```
         |=|     |=|        
         | |     | |        
         | |     | |        
        /   \   /   \       
       .     . .     .      
       |-----| |-----|      
       |     | |     |      
       |-----| |-----|      
       |_____| |_____|      
    =====================    
     |=|     |=|     |=|     
     | |     | |     | |     
     | |     | |     | |     
    /   \   /   \   /   \    
   .     . .     . .     .   
   |-----| |-----| |-----|   
   |     | |     | |     |   
   |-----| |-----| |-----|   
   |_____| |_____| |_____|   
=============================
 [THERE ARE MORE UNDER THIS]
```

*Once again, this is the first two rows from here: https://pastebin.com/ZuXkuH6s (with 1 removed)...*

---

With 2 bottles missing:

```
                 |=|        
                 | |        
                 | |        
                /   \       
               .     .      
               |-----|      
               |     |      
               |-----|      
               |_____|      
    =====================    
     |=|     |=|     |=|     
     | |     | |     | |     
     | |     | |     | |     
    /   \   /   \   /   \    
   .     . .     . .     .   
   |-----| |-----| |-----|   
   |     | |     | |     |   
   |-----| |-----| |-----|   
   |_____| |_____| |_____|   
=============================
 [THERE ARE MORE UNDER THIS]
```

---

## [ADDITIONAL INPUTS REMOVED]

---

With 91 bottles missing (`n = 91`):

```
:(
```

You must output an unhappy face, because you're out of beer.

---

## Rules

- Bottles are to be removed left to right.
- Shelves are removed when no beer remains on the top of the shelves.
- For an input of 0, you are outputting 91 bottles stacked in a triangle.

  - The bottom row has 13 bottles, the top has 1.
- 1 space between each bottle on each shelf.
- Shelves must be input between each row of bottles.

  - Shelves may use `=`, `-` or `#` as the character.
  - Shelves must be 3 wider (on each side) than the bottles they hold.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest byte-count wins.

Comment: Could you provide, say, a pastebin of at least one of the entire test cases?

Comment: Are trailing spaces after a shelf's last bottle required?

Comment: Preceding spaces are required, as you are removing them left to right, the spaces to the right of the ASCII-art are up to you.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien seeing as you didn't specify which test case, I wish I had put an unhappy face in a pastebin ;P.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Because that's a helpful way to make your challenge improve

Comment: Oh, I thought you had chosen 91 to prevent any kind of built-ins. o0

Comment: [The full pastebin you linked to](https://pastebin.com/ZuXkuH6s) has a typo: the third to last row of `=` has 4 extra on each side, when it should only have 3.

Comment: Can we print a shelf under the bottom row or above the top row?

Answer (score 15):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>99</s> 91 bytes

```
Ａ⁻⁹¹ＮθＡ¹³η:(Ｗθ«Ａ⌊⟦θη⟧ζＡ⁻θζθＡ⁻η¹ηＦζ«↑⁴↖.\↑²←|=↓³←↙¹↓.Ｐ⁶↓²Ｐ⁶↓¹Ｐ______←| »¿θ«Ｍ⁹↑Ｍ³→×=⁻×⁸ζ³↑Ｍ⁴←
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZFNa8MwDIbPya8QPtnglqUpY83oYbDLYBljbKd1jLY4tSFxPpy00C2/3XPtliTtDvVNrx69sqQ1X1brfJlq/aCU2EgcC9koPAsoPMmiqV@abMUqTAiFktz7RygIKXATvlZC1hhFGJlgx0XKAJcEfnyvcxNZk@HP0hR8GZO9Ab1Bq/IgOvdhglMIiOvjJXkFeG@dPdc0@igoTA@5TnhmSU0BjRcLNExQmPSFI/c7H2CP@U5SCK0U51vmuHPC1QaXhWjs3OImrUVhM7eX1OQKJjhn0Ld96L8ZwKqt74nktHv3@xkFM3k3jTlZ9CY2vD/Ru8iYwmiOKLidO@HOnSQkpLeMvtfUeJ2W0/qt1jd6tNUjlf4B) Link is to verbose version of code. Actually the [real version](https://tio.run/##hZBPT8MwDMXP7aewcnKkbKL7p61oNy4gWvUAt0moTBmraJuoTcYB9tlD2gQoFGk3v@efny3vj3mzF3lpzEE0gNGSQl8UFDLdHlEzeKXXYdYUtUISI7GiB5Ki1i1uIga3tdQq1dUzb5BSCu9h0BOpUJgJidqbwZ2uJM4ZpPwlVxw31GYFgYt@KCreItkSBllpg5cMnLW2hg9xfCJOHONH@SMWDOJ7flCdcw59oCUYLDrrW3cMAzLd7cgvn8FsoD31sR1CN@KtZjDvHLf/a9@g7waj0RSZ9kmJLlUh@8ZqxMwuEtEfwj/syT5sRf85n4xuPRtzZSYnM2nLTw) is only <s>83</s> 70 bytes:

```
Ｆ¹⁵Ｆι⊞υκ:(Ｆ⁻⁹¹Ｎ«Ｆ¬⊟υ«Ｍ³±⁹×=⁺⁵×⁸⊟υ↑Ｍ⁴←»↑⁴↖.\↑²←|=↓³←↙¹↓.Ｐ⁶↓²Ｐ⁶↓¹Ｐ×_⁶←|←
```

Explanation:

```
Ｆ¹⁵Ｆι⊞υκ
```

Populate an array providing information as to where the shelves go and how long they are.

```
:(
```

Print an unhappy face, although this will be immediately overwritten by the first bottle of beer (if any).

```
Ｆ⁻⁹¹Ｎ«
```

Loop through the remaining bottles of beer.

```
   Ｆ¬⊟υ«
```

Check to see whether a shelf needs to be drawn.

```
        Ｍ³±⁹×=⁺⁵×⁸⊟υ↑Ｍ⁴←»
```

Print the shelf and position ready to draw the next bottle above it.

```
   ↑⁴↖.\↑²←|=↓³←↙¹↓.Ｐ⁶↓²Ｐ⁶↓¹Ｐ×_⁶←|←
```

Draw a bottle and position ready to draw another bottle.

Comment: Huh. Too bad this challenge isn't about *99* bottles of beer. Gotta get 8 bytes down :) :P

Comment: @HyperNeutrino I guess 88 wouldn't be any better?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino It is about *91* bottles though :p

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer That's why I suggested golfing 8 bytes :P And yay he actually did golf 8 bytes :D

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Not exactly; I golfed 11, then ungolfed 3...

Comment: Hmm, I see `Ａ⁻η¹η` (Assign `η-1` to `η`) used pretty often (same applies to +1). Why isn't there a shorter way to do this with just two or three bytes? It's  a pretty basic thing to do in loops.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Normally you'd increment using a `for` loop. This is a `while` loop, so I have to do some thing more manually.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Although, thinking about it, a `for` loop was the way to go all along... 13 bytes saved! (Well, I got a bit lucky with the ease of populating my array.)

Comment: Huh, I just noticed that I can use `-` for my shelves... that would save 2 bytes (remove the `×=`).

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.6), <strike>306</strike> <strike>299</strike> <strike>265</strike> <strike>253</strike> <strike>255</strike> <strike>252</strike> <strike>247</strike> 244 bytes

Quick attempt, could be optimised

**Edit:** -2 bytes thanks to [@MrXcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder)

**Edit:** -32 bytes as trailing spaces is not needed

**Edit:** -12 bytes by combining the two functions

**Edit:** -5 bytes thanks to [@musicman523](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69054/musicman523)

**Edit:** +7 bytes to remove the shelf after the last row

**Edit:** -3 bytes

**Edit:** -5 bytes due to a lambda function only being used once in a map

**Edit:** -3 bytes by using the string function `center`

```python
def l(y,x=13,z=" "):b=min(x,91-y);A,D="  |%s|  ","|-----|";print(y<91and(l(y+x,x-1)or"".join(map(lambda t:((t+z)*b)[:-1].center(103)+"\n",(A%"=",A%z,A%z," /   \ ",".     .",D,"|     |",D,"|_____|")))+z*(49-4*x)+"="*(x*8+5)*(x<13))or(x>12)*":(")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY7RaoQwEEV/ZRgQZmJim7qF1d0UhP2LbilaLd1Fo9g8RMm/27g9MMxlHs6daXE/o823re2@oadFeqNzuRoE5LIxw82Sl4VWC58qeYlnCMlvAECJQe0EPE3zzTpazoWubUtRknrpleZxRszuY1QM9UR9PTRtDa4kcunKouH3UumP7KuzrptJP@ec4tWipCpBg7JK1scgPAHAdW/MYCdDeYntjxz@8@dOQGZOV0GHQh2EjzaDgrw4pq8c91nnHF8i/6ZfWGBJyFtPhebtDw)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder that won't work for x = 2, x=4, x=5, x=7, ...

Comment: Oh, you're right. Sorry!

Comment: [You can put `d=` in the header though, since it is not recursive for -2 bytes](https://tio.run/##RVDRasMwDHzfVxhBwbKdrllaaGM8KPQvmjASkrGa1CleVpLgf8/kPGz3pDukO0mPafjqXbY0pli66l43FRvzjqeZOqXJiL2HnMNL036yjo9qUrMBBpjX5n5zUUBtzSz4XtAI9csM9VNZYyWJR8HHpEZUVkLhQHuSn7o3fzle8lHUeM2TtNRndSFvFjbfgTEGqucQkohAgdq3w493bHrfVa6JuySpmmJgz88bMIDXrnXcYl6uyozijQpgr@RVkF1shC2L2EZ2iTysPPzzj4iVW2lprX0pyZvOEEd5wPUK@ggsD39zA2/4DnH5BQ)

Comment: [248 bytes](https://tio.run/##RY7dasMwDEZfRQgKkn@6OV2gTeZBoW@xjpGQjRVSu3S5cILfPZN7s@9C6Oji6LvN008Mu3Udvr5hpNkk73Zm8QjITe@vl0DJHJyduY1@7K790MHULIrqWr@oZPeqZ02TzPfGug@N54Dt0ZxEAHnzmwEATSTMtiSLtb3dL2Gi@fXgujCQ/NTJJOs43iHScYMeWZdlYVXJgvAkkrN4yhm3ULItdCqcH5z/@bPkwaVlZaUla5EqSmqva5Y/lN5cxQobQl5Heub1Dw) by removing the `E` variable

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>251</s> 256 bytes

**Edit:** *Saved 2 bytes thanks to [@dzaima](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59183/dzaima).*
**Edit:** *Added 7 bytes to fix issue with parameter. `:(`*

```js
c=>(f=(c,w=13)=>c>0&&f(c-w,w-1)+(c=c<w?c:w,r=(n,s=' ')=>s.repeat(n),a='\n'+r(52-w*4),'  |=|  0  | |  0  | |  0 /   \\ 0.     .0|-----|0|     |0|-----|0|_____|'.split(0).map(x=>a+r((w-c)*8+2)+r(c,' '+x)).join('')+a+r(w*8+5,'#')),(c=91-c)?f(c).slice(6):':(')
```

Here's the (mostly) ungolfed version:

```js
function (consumed) {
  let remaining = 91 - consumed;

  function inner (count, width = 13) {
    if (count <= 0) return false;

    function repeat (count, string = ' ') {
      return string.repeat(count);
    }

    const pattern = [
      '  |=|  ',
      '  | |  ',
      '  | |  ',
      ' /   \\ ',
      '.     .',
      '|-----|',
      '|     |',
      '|-----|',
      '|_____|' ];

    let clamped = Math.min(count, width);
    let alignment = '\n' + repeat((13 - width) * 4);
    let empty = alignment + repeat((width - clamped) * 8 + 2);
    let shelf = alignment + repeat((width * 8) + 5, '#');
    let bottles = pattern.map(row => empty + repeat(clamped, ' ' + row));

    return inner(count - width, width - 1) + bottles.join('') + shelf;
  }

  return (remaining) ? inner(remaining).slice(6) : ':(';
}
```

#### Test code

```js
const golfed =

c=>(f=(c,w=13)=>c>0&&f(c-w,w-1)+(c=c<w?c:w,r=(n,s=' ')=>s.repeat(n),a='\n'+r(52-w*4),'  |=|  0  | |  0  | |  0 /   \\ 0.     .0|-----|0|     |0|-----|0|_____|'.split(0).map(x=>a+r((w-c)*8+2)+r(c,' '+x)).join('')+a+r(w*8+5,'#')),(c=91-c)?f(c).slice(6):':(')

console.log(golfed(91)); // :(
console.log(golfed(72));
//                                                          |=|     |=|     |=|     |=|     |=|     |=|
//                                                          | |     | |     | |     | |     | |     | |
//                                                          | |     | |     | |     | |     | |     | |
//                                                         /   \   /   \   /   \   /   \   /   \   /   \
//                                                        .     . .     . .     . .     . .     . .     .
//                                                        |-----| |-----| |-----| |-----| |-----| |-----|
//                                                        |     | |     | |     | |     | |     | |     |
//                                                        |-----| |-----| |-----| |-----| |-----| |-----|
//                                                        |_____| |_____| |_____| |_____| |_____| |_____|
//     #####################################################################################################
//      |=|     |=|     |=|     |=|     |=|     |=|     |=|     |=|     |=|     |=|     |=|     |=|     |=|
//      | |     | |     | |     | |     | |     | |     | |     | |     | |     | |     | |     | |     | |
//      | |     | |     | |     | |     | |     | |     | |     | |     | |     | |     | |     | |     | |
//     /   \   /   \   /   \   /   \   /   \   /   \   /   \   /   \   /   \   /   \   /   \   /   \   /   \
//    .     . .     . .     . .     . .     . .     . .     . .     . .     . .     . .     . .     . .     .
//    |-----| |-----| |-----| |-----| |-----| |-----| |-----| |-----| |-----| |-----| |-----| |-----| |-----|
//    |     | |     | |     | |     | |     | |     | |     | |     | |     | |     | |     | |     | |     |
//    |-----| |-----| |-----| |-----| |-----| |-----| |-----| |-----| |-----| |-----| |-----| |-----| |-----|
//    |_____| |_____| |_____| |_____| |_____| |_____| |_____| |_____| |_____| |_____| |_____| |_____| |_____|
// #############################################################################################################
```

Comment: Very impressive, great answer. I like your `r` "macro"; I felt like there could be a shorter method but nothing I tried brought it down any.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>360</strike> 358 bytes

```c
#define P printf(
r,i,j;char*b[]={"  |=|  ","  | |  ","  | |  "," /   \\ ",".     .","|-----|","|     |","|-----|","|_____|"};w(n){P"%*c",n,' ');}main(n,a)char**a;{(n=-atoi(a[1]))<-90?P":(\n"):({while(++r<14)if((n+=r)>0){for(j=0;j<9;++j){w(4*(13-r)+1);for(i=r;i>0;)--i<n?P b[j]),w(1):w(8);P"\n");}if(r<13){w(4*(13-r)-2);for(i=0;++i<8*r+6;)P"=");P"\n");}}});}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7BasMwEETv/YpFpWTXklK7SUtiWckv@B6borh2I9MqRQR8sP3trhUobegclscsO7OVfK@qabp/qxvrasjhy1t3afDOCytaVZ2Mj46HUvcMYNADABOB4B89AkBRBFxC0HKmQQYNga7ecOu9Bg1sVB066nP2EFVMOLGABanx01iHThi6vhAZ1aPT0lzOFs0hKYkyuY33OUuxcIxS7LuT/aiRc58la7INouPa0y6mvjl7bHWs2myrOG@p73AdYbKSnnhCKqyt9sruYkVS2sztczge2pJEhwmlHW5I5SzUqHEOngtWfzPk009GPMfbbBN5/qIoZ5r93o3jPKZpeo6/AQ)

**Explanation:**

```c
#define P printf(
r,i,j;
char*b[]={
    "  |=|  ",
    "  | |  ",
    "  | |  ",
    " /   \\ ",
    ".     .",
    "|-----|",
    "|     |",
    "|-----|",
    "|_____|"};

// function to print `n` spaces:
w(n){P"%*c",n,' ');}

main(n,a)char**a;
{
    // no beer left?
    (n=-atoi(a[1]))<-90

        // sad face
        ?P":(\n")

        // else create stack
        // using GCC extension "expression statement" `({ <statement> })` here,
        // shorter than if-else or a function call
        :({
            // loop over 13 rows
            while(++r<14)

                // found non-empty row?
                if((n+=r)>0)
                {
                    // loop over text lines of beer bottles
                    for(j=0;j<9;++j)
                    {
                        w(4*(13-r)+1);

                        // for each bottle
                        for(i=r;i>0;)

                            // print either 8 spaces or line of the bottle
                            --i<n?P b[j]),w(1):w(8);P"\n");
                    }

                    // except for last row, ...
                    if(r<13)
                    {
                        // ... print shelf
                        w(4*(13-r)-2);
                        for(i=0;++i<8*r+6;)
                            P"=");
                        P"\n");
                    }
                }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 436 bytes

<sup>*Yikes!!*</sup>

My method is too verbose, but anyway: it essentially 'draws' each row of bottles, adds in the spaces, and then 'erases' whatever necessary, printing whatever is left.

```
B=['  |=|   ','  | |   ','  | |   ',' /   \\  ','.     . ','|-----| ','|     | ','|-----| ','|_____| ']
N=lambda r:sum(n for n in range(1,r+1))
n=input()
R=0
while N(R)<n:R+=1
L=R-n+N(R-1)
e=range(1,R)+([R],[])[L!=0]
for r in range(1,14):
    if r in e:continue
    if(r-1 in e)<1:print('',' '*(1+(13-r)*4)+'='*(r*8-3))[r!=1]
    i=(0,R-L)[r==R];w=(8*i+(13-r)*4,0)[i==0];print'\n'.join([' '*w+((13-r)*4*' '+l*r)[w:]for l in B])
if n=91:print':('
```

Halvard Hummel's is much better.